# MassTransit and third party message format

Tags: masstransit

I'm thinking about to migrate current system to MassTransit. Now it consumes messages that coming from IoT devices from RabbitMQ and it's not in the format that MassTransit expects.

So, my question is about what options do I have in order integrate MassTransit into the project? So far I can see it as custom proxy that reads messages from RabbitMQ and publish it back with MassTransit. Is it good one ore there are some other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message format is JSON, MassTransit has built-in support for consuming plain (RAW) JSON, as outlined [in the documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization#raw-json).

Comment: just curious, what is the message format is not JSON?

Comment: you'd need to write your own deserializer. Raw XML is available from the MassTransit.Newtonsoft package.